# is there pybind11 method that has similar properties of PyString_AsString

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, python-c-api, pybind11

I am trying to convert the c++ project  from boost to pybind11

```
QString r = QString(PyString_AsString(result));"

QString r = QString(py::str(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Pybind11 think you need to go through a `std::string`

```
QString r = QString(result.cast<std::string>().c_str());"
```

You could of course just use `PyString_AsString` yourself:

```
QString r = QString(PyString_AsString(result.ptr());
```

---

`PyString_AsString` is from a Python version that has been completely unsupported for >2 years. You should consider whether you should be using it at all.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer, avoid using `PyString_AsString`, that is a raw C python api call.

Instead convert the python string to a `std::string`

```
std::string intermediateStdString = std::string(py::str(result));
```

Then you can convert that `std::string` to a `QString`

```
QString finalQString = QString::fromStdString(intermediateStdString));
```